# Mongoose createIndex on node startup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m building a `mongoose` application using `node.js`, using `nodemon` to restart node on code update.

Every time the code is restarted I get mongoose messages for every collection on my DB like:

```
Mongoose: users.createIndex({ username: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
```

My mongoose start code looks like:

```
// Connect to mongoose
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/testdb';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
    useMongoClient: true
});
```

I wish to understand what is going on with these `createIndex` messages:

Is mongoose recriating all indexes on every code start ? 
If so, how can I configure it to use already created indexes ?
Will that happen in production also ?

Thanks for helping me to understand that behaviour.

Comment: Mongoose will ensure that the indices that you set up in your schemas exist in the database whenever it initializes. You can disable this feature by passing `{ autoIndex: false }` to your Mongoose schema options. More information: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#autoIndex

Comment: Yes, but it is recreating the indexes on each startup ? `createIndex` seens to be different than `ensureIndex`...

Comment: I believe `ensureIndex` is deprecated in favor of `createIndex` since MongoDB 3.0. `createIndex` should not create an index if it already exists. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/